# How to make roles in yii

Tags: php, yii

So i am new to the yii framework and i am doing this blog style of a website trying to cover most of the features i can think off and the one I am stuck at is the having differnet user roles for example.

Lets say we have a writer and a normal logged in user and i want to make a writer when he go on the article page he can see some buttons while a normal loged in user can only see the comment button.

How do i come up with something to do this inside of the Yii Framework? and tutorials i can find on the internet?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

List all roles in `User` model

```
class User extends MyModel {

   const ROLE_ADMIN = 1,
      ROLE_AUTHOR = 2,
      ROLE_USER = 3;
```

Also add `role` field to user (in database and in model).

In `components/UserIdentity.php` add some methods

```
public function isAuthor() {
     return !empty($this->user) && $this->user->role == User::ROLE_AUTHOR;
}

public function isGuest(){
     return empty($this->user);
}
```

Also, I recommend to add this method to `User` model:

```
public function getRole($role = null) {
     $roles = [
         self::ROLE_ADMIN => 'Admin',
         self::ROLE_AUTHOR => 'Author',
         self::ROLE_USER => 'User',
     ];

     if (!is_null($role)) {
         return isset($roles[$role]) ? $roles[$role] : 'Unknown role';
     }

     return $roles;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response i will try it later when i get home. I'l keep you up dated :)

Comment: Okay now i have done this, How do i use this now, sorry very new to the frame work :/

Comment: @Colosuslol `Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()` => allow to go to admin pages, else return to login

Answer (score 0):

Hello thank you for the help that other people gave me but I have a found a a simple guide which i understood very easily and its very nice to use. you can find the tutorial in the following  [Link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/191/implementing-a-user-level-access-system) . Thank you For you help guys!